# Filtering based on many-many and avoiding duplicates

Tags: django, django-models

I am new to using Many-Many fields and I really could not find a good example that explained on how to go on with this task.

I currently have two models `modelJob` and `modelSkillSubscription` now `modelJob` contains a Many-To-Maney fields of skills.

What I would like to do is 
retrieve `modelSkillSubscription` if they contain any of the skills that I have obtained. Say `modelJob` contains [SkillA,SkillB,SkillC]. I would like to pass this to a filter and obtain all `modelSkillSubscription` that contains any of the skills from the List avoiding duplicates.

```
class modelJob(models.Model):
    skills              = models.ManyToManyField(modelSkill,blank=True)


class modelSkillSubscription(models.Model):
    employer            = models.ForeignKey(modelEmployer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=True)
    skills              = models.ManyToManyField(modelSkill, blank=True)
```

Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the `SkillSubscription` models based on an existing `Job` instance (I'd drop the leading `model`, making the model name shorter and compliant with Python “CamelCase” class naming conventions):

```
job = Job.objects.get(id=1)
subscriptions = (SkillSubscription.objects
    .filter(skills__in=job.skills.all())
    .distinct()
)
```

This selects all subscriptions that have at least one skill in common with the job.

You can also wrap the job selection in the same query if you know the filter criteria:

```
subscriptions = (SkillSubscription.objects
    .filter(skills__in=Job.objects.filter(
                                      # your filter criteria
                                  )
                                  .values('skills'))
    .distinct()
)
```